# magento 2.2.3 custom template not loading

Tags: frontend, magento2.2.3

I have installed my extension on magento 2.2.3 it is working but one frontend phtml file is not loading. Is there any other way to register custom template in 2.2.3? Also it works fine in 2.1.9 and other files are working fine in 2.2.3.

Comment: Which file is it? Is it an override of an existing PHTML file in your custom theme? Or a custom file that's loaded by a custom block in a layout XML file? Can you give us some more details about this?

Comment: I am trying to load default.php renderer in sales/shipment. It is an existing phtml file I want to load in my custom module not in theme.